# Azure AD Angular Customize login respose

Tags: angular, azure, azure-active-directory, jwt, azure-ad-msal

Experts, I need your help with this.

Is there any way that I can add a custom key and value to the Azure AD login response.

Example,

I need to add a custom key called `myownkey` and a value `myownkeyvalue`.

```
environment:"login.windows.net"
homeAccountId:"ID_1.ID_2"
.
.
myownkey: "myownkeyvalue"
.
.
.
idTokenClaims:Object
    aio:"xxx"
    aud:"xxx"
    exp:1661778482
    iat:1661774582
    .
    .
    .
    tid:"xxx"
    uti:"xxx"
    ver:"xxx"
```

Comment: Could you confirm whether adding that custom key and value in **id token** claims satisfies your requirement?

Comment: Sounds like an option. Could you please advise me with steps or a documentations that I can refer to try this option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To add custom key and value in **id token** claims, you can create
> claim mapping policy using  **PowerShell**.

Make sure to have  **`AzureADPreview`**  module installed, before running below script:

```
Connect-AzureAD
New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('
{
    "ClaimsMappingPolicy":
    {
        "Version":1,"IncludeBasicClaimSet":"true", 
        "ClaimsSchema": [{"Source":"user","ID":"extensionattribute1","SamlClaimType":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/mycustomkey","JwtClaimType":"mycustomkey"}]
    }
}') -DisplayName "CustomKeyClaim" -Type "ClaimsMappingPolicy"
```

**Response:**

[image]

Note the  **`ID`**  from above response and assign it to your service principal using below command:

```
Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id <serviceprincipal_ObjectID> -RefObjectId <policy_ID>
```

To **confirm** whether the policy is assigned or not, run below command:

```
Get-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id <serviceprincipal_ObjectID>
```

**Response:**

[image]

Now, assign  **value**  to that claim by signing into  **[Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)**  and run the below query:

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me
{
"onPremisesExtensionAttributes": 
    {
        "extensionAttribute1": "customvalue"
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

Make sure to set  **`"acceptMappedClaims": true`**  in App's Manifest like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App registrations -> Your App -> Manifest***

[image]

Now, I generated tokens using **authorization code** flow via Postman like below:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:appID
client_secret:secret
scope: profile User.Read openid
code:<code>
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**

[image]

After decoding the above ***ID token***  in  [**jwt.ms**](https://jwt.ms/), I got custom key and value in claims successfully as below:

[image]